# Aurelia Navigation event seems to be triggered too early

Tags: routes, aurelia

#### What I want to achieve

I have a list of items which is shown in a grid. When you click on one of the items it is navigating to the details of the item. On that page I would like to retrieve some information about the dom to do some actions based on the dom.

#### The issue

If I subscribe to the event (using the event aggregator) **router:navigation:complete** of Aurelia and do a console.log here then it shows me the DOM information of the list instead of the DOM information of the details page.

[Events of the router](http://ilikekillnerds.com/2015/09/understanding-aurelia-router-events/)

Am I subscribing to the wrong event?

Answer (score 0):

declare one variable as currentActivePage: string; and navigation sucess event in app.js as well as where ever you required.

```
currentActivePage: string;
self.eventAggregator.subscribe('router:navigation:success', obj => {
            if (obj !== undefined) {
                self.currentActivePage = obj.instruction.config.name;
            }
            //self.prepareTabs(obj.instruction.config);
        });
```

And same mentioned you can use in where ever you required. and in HTML you can show or hide the dom based on condition like below

```
<div class="${currentActivePage == 'PageName' ? 'DisplayNone':'DisplayBlock'}">
content will go here
</div>
```